# Finding number of primes between floor(n^2/2)+1 and n^2

Tags: c++, math, primes

I was trying to find a program that returned the number of primes between $floor(n^2/2)+1$ and $n^2$.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main() {
    int cnt=0;

    for(int i=3;i<=100;i++){
        cnt = 0;
        for(int j=(i^2/2)+1; j<(i^2); j++)
        {
            if(isPrime(j))
            {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        cout << i << " " << cnt << endl;
    }
}
```

is my code, but I got

```
3 0
4 0
5 1
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 1
14 0
15 0
16 0
17 1
18 0
```

... etc, so I don't know what went wrong here.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What output do you expect? Try adding more detailed logging or use a debugger to figure out what's happening where, and where your expectations differ from what actually happens. Try testing `isPrime` directly.

Comment: Build up an array with information on which numbers are prime first (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You can even save it to disk and use it later. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` Don't use this, it is not a standard C++ header.  And also `using namespace std;`  is not recommended. (Where are you learning C++ from?)

Answer (score 1):

in C++, `i^2` does a bitwise XOR operation, it is not for exponents, you can replace this with `pow(i, 2)` or `i*i`

Comment: use `i*=2` not `i*i`, and you might run into rounding errors with pow (and it is less efficient). This is an integer problem not a floating point one so don't mix floating point with integer calculations

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yeah, `pow` is a bad idea here. WDYM about `i*=2`? That would double `i` in-place. `i*i` is the best option here.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes you are right, totally got sqr(2) wrong there